# Python: How to use a Variable Integer to Call a Specific Part of a String

Tags: python, string, variables

Ok, so I've got a couple issues with a program (for school again) that I'm using to add up all the digits of a number. I've got some of the program down, except 2 things. First, how to use a variable (thelength below) in replacement of a number to call a specific digit of the input (I'm not sure if this is even possible, but it would be helpful). And second, how to add up different numbers in a string. Any ideas?

Here's what I have so far:

```
number = str(int(input("Please type a number to add up: ")))
length = len(number)
thelength = 0
total = 0
thenumbers = []
while thelength < length:
    #The issue is me trying to use thelength in the next two lines, and the fact that number is now a string
    total += number[thelength]
    thenumbers.append(number[thelength])
    thelength += 1
for num in thenumbers:
    print(num[0])
print("+")
print("___")
print(total)
```

Thanks for any help I can get!

Comment: So you're summing all of the digits of the input number?

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to enter a number with any number of digits and have all those digits added up.

Comment: why are you casting to an int then a string? input is aready a string

Comment: Oh. I'm a bit new to python. I didn't think that an input was a string. That makes things a bit easier

Comment: what about negative numbers or floats?

Comment: @1adog1 - How `input` works changed between python 2.x and 3.x. In 2.x, `input` evaluates the string (so, entering "111" would evaluate to an int) and `raw_input` just passes in the string unchanged. Since evaluating user input strings is dangerous, python 3.x changed `input` to just return the string and got rid of `raw_input` completely. Many examples on the net are 2.x based so its easy to get confused.

Comment: You never mention what the problem is. Is it raising an exception? Can you post that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import sys

INPUT_VALIDATOR = re.compile("^[0-9]+$")

input_str = input("Please type a natural number to add up: ")

if INPUT_VALIDATOR.match(input_str) is None:
    print ("Your input was not a natural number (a positive whole number greater or equal to zero)!")
    print ("This displeases me, goodbye puny human.")
    sys.exit(1)

total = 0
for digit_str in input_str:
    print(digit_str)
    total += int(digit_str)
print("+")
print("___")
print(total)
```

If you don't need to print the digits as you go, it's even easier:

```
# (Add the same code as above to get and validate the input string)
print(sum(int(digit_str) for digit_str in input_str))
```

Comment: `str(int(input` is not needed, why cast to an int then to a string then back to an int when summing?

Comment: It was done that way in the original question, I assume that passes for validation. Obviously you could validate the string input with a regexp etc and then int() it, but that seems to shift focus from the original problem.

Comment: I don't think there is any case where  it would make sense to cast a string which is already a string to a string where in the middle of all that it is cast to an int.

Comment: It's to reject/fix inputs such as `1.2` and `i+1`. It won't catch inputs like `-1`. I'm not suggesting it's 'good' validation, but I think it's off the point of the original question.

Comment: if you wanted to validate you would use a try/except. I don't think doing something the correct way is ever off the point.

Comment: I hope the new validation pleases you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "call a specific digit of the input" means, but the error in your code is here:

```
total += number[thelength]
```

`total` is an int, and you're trying to add a string to it, convert the digit to an integer first.

```
total += int(number[thelength])
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
+
___
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing that you need is convert the digits to `int` and sum them :

```
>>> s='1247'
>>> sum(map(int,s))
14
```

But as you get the number from input it could cause a `ValueErorr` , for refuse that you can use a `try-except` :

```
try :
  print sum(map(int,s))

except ValueErorr :
  print 'please write a valin number :'
```

Also if you are using python 2 use `raw_input` for get the number or if you are using python 3 just use `input` because the result of both is string !

Comment: `s='-1247'` is also a number

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input("Please type a number to add up: "))
total = 0
while number > 0:
    total += number % 10
    total /= 10
print(total)
```

num % 10 pretty much gets the last digit of a number

then we divide it by 10 to truncate the number by its last digit

we can loop through the number as long as it's above 0 and take the digital sum by using the method outlined above